# Why does my email are sended directly into spam?

Tags: laravel, email

I'm creating an application that needs to send email to every die insert. I'm using Laravel's mailable tool, but whenever I send an email, it ends up falling in the spam box.

**My form to send e-mail**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
      <form action="{{ route('sendmail')}}" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="mailaddress">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="title">
        <button type="submit">Send me a mail</button>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My routes**

```
Route::post('/sendmail', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer){

  $mailer->to($request->input('mail'))->send(new \App\Mail\MyMail($request->input('title')));

  return redirect()->back();
})->name('sendmail');
```

My `.ENV` Configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Any suggestion? I'm try to send a simple message, without html tags something else like that. But still going to spam box. Thank's in advance!

Comment: It may have to do with your SMTP host?

Comment: Email deliverability is really too broad / offtopic for SO.  Could be hundreds of reasons why an email is viewed as spam ranging from content to the IP address.

Comment: How about a TXT record like `v=spf1 ip4:YOUR.IP ~all`?

Comment: Add the following headers as well with valid data: From: me@mydomain.com

Reply-To: me@hotmail.com

Comment: In Gmail my code works, but in Outlook or custom e-mail don't work. Maybe the error is in Header, I gonna try to use your code!